# psql Not Showing Tables Even Though pgAdmin Shows Them

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I am running a postgres instance on a VM which is on a "host" computer.

I have created tables and they are visible on the pgAdmin tool when connected remotely from the host computer to the VM (as you can see there are 8 tables listed in the gui), however when I try to show the tables when logging in from the VM with psql (psql -U myapp -h localhost and then \dt) I don't see them! Please help!

[image]

`postgres@postgresql:~$ psql -U myapp Password for user myapp:  psql (9.4.5) Type "help" for help. myapp=>  myapp=> \dt No relations found.`

Comment: see this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110550/why-cant-i-see-my-table-postgresql-when-i-use-dt-inside-psql

Comment: Hi Being Sunny, that post you shared is referring to a different issue because /dt+ public also gives no result

Comment: It is `\dt public.*`

Comment: Is the database running locally? Does `$ psql -U myapp -h 192.168.2.2` get the same behaviour? Try to change pgAdmin host from 192.168.2.2 to localhost and check if tables still appear.

Comment: Hi Christian. Thanks. The database is on a VM running from what I will call the "host" computer in this comment. When I tried psql -U myapp -h 192.168.2.2 with \dt on the "host" computer of VM it worked, I did not need to enter a password,  and I saw the tables! However when I put in psql -U myapp -h 192.168.2.2 or with local on the VM, I am prompted with a password and /dt shows nothing. Why is that???

Comment: sounds like you logged in with a user that does not have rights

Comment: @Hogan as I described above actually it is the same user both times. Only once I am logging in as the user from the VM and once I am logging in remotely as that same user, and the tables were created when logged in as that user but remotely. You are aware of that when you make that comment?

Comment: So the user had rights to create tables and view them on remote, but to view those tables on local it did not have rights - only ability to log in and to view tables that were only created by the user on local but not remote? - that is what I'm seeing. Is that a role permissions issue on postgres side??

Comment: Even aware as I am now, I think it sounds like you logged in with a user that does not have rights. Check the logs -- is there an access violation?  It is possible that your local vs remote access is using a different user than you think?